# How to insert characters inline VS Code Snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, timestamp, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Trying to create a timestamp snippet in VS Code that produces `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`.

**Tried so far:**

`$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE","T","$CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND","Z"` but the commas place each section on a new line.

```
2021-06-27
T
08:57:03
Z
```

How do I get the "T" and "Z" characters *inline* here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things:

1. Put the whole thing on one line - the `,`'s are seen as line breaks.
2. Wrap each variable in `${....}` so that they work properly with the other charcters `T` and `Z` right next to them.  Otherwise the variables cannot be interpreted properly.  So:

`"${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}T${CURRENT_HOUR}:${CURRENT_MINUTE}:${CURRENT_SECOND}Z"`

Comment: There it is! Thank you.