# How to capture UTC instead of local time in VS Code timestamp snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, timestamp, code-snippets

So I've now got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152953/how-to-insert-characters-inline-vs-code-snippet) great timestamp inside a code snippet in VS Code.

**Full snippet:**

```
"Frontmatter":{
        "prefix": "sqFront",
        "body": [
            "---",
            "title: $1",
            "permalink: $2",
            "description: $3",
            "date: ${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}T${CURRENT_HOUR}:${CURRENT_MINUTE}:${CURRENT_SECOND}Z",
            "tags:",
              "- $0",
            "---"
        ]
    }
```

**How do I set the snippet to capture UTC time instead of my local time?**

Comment: Some options here: maybe one of the extensions mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) extension:

Define the following snippet in the `language.hsnips` file or in `all.hsnips` file if you want to have it many file types

```
snippet sqFront "Frontmatter" b
---
title: $1
permalink: $2
description: $3
date: `` d = new Date();
twodigit = n => n.toString().padStart(2,'0');
rv = `${d.getUTCFullYear()}-${twodigit(d.getUTCMonth()+1)}-${twodigit(d.getUTCDate())}T${twodigit(d.getUTCHours())}:${twodigit(d.getUTCMinutes())}:${twodigit(d.getUTCSeconds())}Z` ``
tags:
- $0
---
endsnippet
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this natively? I've got all my extensions dialed at the moment. Sometime introducing another one causes breakage. Would prefer to do this natively if its possible.

Comment: @SeaDude most (native) VSC behavior is done with extensions, so if you eliminate extensions VSC does nothing

Comment: Gotcha. I was thinking since there are built-in variables such as `CURRENT_HOUR`, etc. there may be a built in `CURRENT_HOUR_UTC` or the like. Or a way to define a timezone that VS Code uses for a snippet, etc.